# How to get(handle) Error (Not Acceptable & Internal Server Error) Exception content in Ajax

Tags: ajax

I added internal Error (throw exception) in server side. Now I want to handle this error in client side. However , I get error content undefined.

I am using Postman , and see my response is JSON format, it has response parameter like "Message". I tried to parse JSON , and again I got `Cannot read property 'Message' of undefined`

Ajax function defined like this:

```
function Ajax(url, method,  json, successFunction, errorFunction, skipErrorDlg) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: json,
    type: method,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', GlobalAuthToken);
    },
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        successFunction(data);
    },
    error: function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
        if (errorFunction != null) {
            errorFunction();
        }
    }
});
```

}

I used this function in my code , error part like this, In this function how can I get exception content?

```
function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError)
            {           
                alert("ERROR HAPPENED");
                var responseString = JSON.stringify(event);
                alert(responseString.Message);
                alert("event" + event.Message);

            },
```

Postman Result:

```
{
"Message": "Please select corresponding template."}
```

Expected Result should be : `Please select corresponding template.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, if you face this kind problem , trying like this:

```
function showAjaxError(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    var msg = "";
    if (event.hasOwnProperty('responseJSON')) {
        var resp = event['responseJSON'];
        msg = (resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('Message')) ? resp.Message : "";
        msg = msg + ((resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('ExceptionMessage')) ? "\n\n" + resp.ExceptionMessage : "");
        if (resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('InnerException')) {
            msg = msg + ((resp && resp.InnerException.hasOwnProperty('ExceptionMessage')) ? "\n\n" + resp.InnerException.ExceptionMessage : "");
        }
    } else {
        msg = event.responseText;
    }
}
```